# How to return an array of arrays that contains hashes

Tags: arrays, ruby, hash

This is  my method  that is called by the test function:

```rb
def movies_with_directors_set(source)       
  director = []
  director1 = []
  hash = {}

  while outer_index < source.length do
    inner_index = 0

    while inner_index < source[outer_index][:movies].length do
      hash[:title] = []
      hash[:title] = source[outer_index][:movies][inner_index][:title]
      hash[:director_name] = []
      hash[:director_name] = source[outer_index][:name]

      director1 << hash.dup

      inner_index +=1
    end

    director <<  director1.dup 

    outer_index += 1
  end


  return director
end
```

This is the test code:

```
 describe 'movies_with_directors_set' do
  describe 'when given a Hash with keys :name and :movies,' do
    describe 'returns an Array of Hashes that represent movies' do
      describe 'and each Hash has a :director_name key set with the value that was in :name' do
        # This lets "sample_data" be used in the two "it" statements below
        let (:test_data) {
          [
            { :name => "Byron Poodle", :movies => [
              { :title => "At the park" },
              { :title => "On the couch" },
            ]
            },
            { :name => "Nancy Drew", :movies => [
              { :title => "Biting" },
            ]
            }
          ]
        }

        it 'correctly "distributes" Byron Poodle as :director_name of the first film' do
          # { :name => "A", :movies => [{ :title => "Test" }] }
          # becomes... [[{:title => "Test", :director_name => "A"}], ...[], ... []]
          results = movies_with_directors_set(test_data)
          expect(results.first.first[:director_name]).to eq("Byron Poodle"),
            "The first element of the AoA should have 'Byron Poodle' as :director_name"
        end

        it 'correctly "distributes" Nancy Drew as :director_name of the last film' do
          results = movies_with_directors_set(test_data)
          expect(results.last.first[:director_name]).to eq("Nancy Drew"),
            "The last element of the AoA should have 'Nancy Drew' as :director_name"
        end
      end
    end
  end
end
```

My method returns an array of hashes but for some reason it does not want to pass the test, as it tells me the second part of the test fails.

It could be that it requires arrays within an array due to the way the test is worded.

`source` is the database that gets passed into the method. This specific database is shown in the test code.

Comment: When `outer_index` is first referenced it is undefined, which would raise an exception.

Comment: Tip: Instead of recycling the same hash object, make a new one each time and insert that, as in: `director1 << { ... }`. This ends up being easier to follow and more efficient. You should also work on using `map`, it's the core of how Ruby makes life easier for you and avoiding it leads to needlessly complicated code.

Comment: You could also make your life a lot easier if you used one of `:name` or `:director_name` consistently instead of having two labels for what seems to be the same thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to transform the structure from a nested director-name/titles into director-name/title pairs, there's a much easier way of going about that. Ruby's strength is in the [Enumerable library](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.5/Enumerable.html) which makes data transformation really fast, efficient, and easy to express. Here's an approach worth using:

```
def movies_with_directors(source)
  # flat_map will join together the inner arrays into a single contiguous array
  source.flat_map do |set|
    set[:movies].map do |movie|
      {
        director_name: set[:name],
        title: movie[:title]
      }
    end
  end
end
```

This produces a very flat, easy to navigate structure like this:

```
# => [{:director_name=>"Byron Poodle", :title=>"At the park"}, {:director_name=>"Byron Poodle", :title=>"On the couch"}, {:director_name=>"Nancy Drew", :title=>"Biting"}]
```

Where you can iterate over that and assert more easily without having to do `.first.first` and such.

When using Ruby always try and think in terms of *data transformation*, not in terms of loops. There's a multitude of tools in the Enumerable library that can perform complicated operations with a single line of code. In your case you needed a combination of `flat_map` and `map`, and you're done.

Answer (score 1):

Your test data and test expectations seem to be out of sync.

You have a `:name` key, and then expect `:director_name` to be present in your test hash. Change `:director_name` to be `:name` and it should pass:

```
{ :name => "Nancy Drew", :movies => [
```

and

```
expect(results.last.first[:director_name]).to eq("Nancy Drew")
```

So your failing test is probably saying something like `expected nil to be "Nancy Drew"`, right?

Comment: When answering be careful to not ask a question of the OP unless it's clearly rhetorical. Asking a question can get your answer removed if it appears to be a comment, a reply, or another question instead of a true answer.